# Create JavaScript / jQuery function to use in certain way

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

How does one create a JavaScript or jQuery function to use like

> var return = result.function('param','parameter');

I'm referring to a function like some jQuery libraries that can be used like this(eg Slider).

> $('element').slider(options);

I'm trying to make a function to get dynamic content, what I have so far is =

```
getdata = function(url,param){
  $.ajax({
    url:url,
    success:function(result){
      return result;
    }
  });
}

$('element').getdata('example.com/example.txt','parameter=1');
```

This is how I would need to use it in the end.

Is there any way I can make this work?

Comment: you need to write a jquery plugin. you can find a good startkit [here](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate)

Comment: wow thx sina this is definitely a big help in the future :)

Comment: Pay close attention to what you're doing here, the ajax call is asynchronous, and returning won't be doing what you think it is doing!

Comment: @DaveNewton yes , this is right. I was writng an answer because of this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

According to this guide you can add functions to the `$.fn` object. In their example:

`$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
};
$( "a" ).greenify();`

you can access the underlying javascript elements retrieved from the selector with `this` or you can convert them to jQuery objects with `$(this)`.

For your function you would want to do something like this:

`$.fn.getdata = function(url, param) {
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        success:function(result){
            return result;
        }
    });
};
$('element').getdata('example.com/example.txt','parameter=1');`

There isn't much of a reason to do this though if you aren't using the selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can wirte a basic jquery plugin for this operation

```
$.fn.getdata= function(url,parameters) {
    that = $(this);

$.ajax({
     url:url+"?"parameters,
     data 
       success:function(result){ 
      that.text(result); 
       } });
    };
```

calling it like

```
$('element').getdata('example.com/example.txt','parameter=1');
```

Answer (score 0):

It also depends if you would like your function to be chainable and also how you would like to initialise the plugin. For your above example, you don't really require chaining since the function isn't using the element. However, I would do something like this:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.getdata = function(params) {

        // set default settings and merge what is passed through in params
        var settings = $.extend({
            url : "http://defaultURL.com",
            success : function(result) {
                return result;
            }
        }, params);

        // the ajax call
        $.ajax(settings);

        // return the original jQuery object again to enable chaining
        return this;
    }

}(jQuery));
```

The above creates a self invoking function that passes jQuery through as a parameter, this prevents conflicts with other libraries that you may have that use $ as a reference too.

Using jQuery extend to merge two objects together, that is the parameters.

Then it's possible to call the above function with:

```
$(element).getdata({
    url : 'http://somedifferenturl.com'
});
```

Or

```
$(element).getdata({
    url : 'http://somedifferenturl.com',
    success : function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```